# A tool to convert/translate JSON objects to typescript types/interfaces?

Tags: json, types, interface, typescript

I'm looking for a simple tool to do a simple thing: convert a JSON object to a typescript type or interface.

For instance given one of these: https://api.github.com/users/octocat

I'd like to copy and paste that into the tool and get a structure like this:

```
export interface GitProfile {
  login: string;
  id: number;
  avatar_url: string;
  gravatar_id: string;
  url: string;
  html_url: string;
  followers_url: string;
  following_url: string;
  gists_url: string;
  ...other_parts: part_types;...
}
```

This seems pretty straight forward so I'm crossing my fingers someone already made the tool and I just can't find it. Tempted to make one myself, though I'm a pretty novice programmer and it might take time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed someone has : https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2dts

And I also have IDE support for it in [alm.tools](http://alm.tools)

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/alm/content/features/json-to-dts.html

[image]

Comment: Cool! That is an awesome project.

Comment: The web tool is absurdly perfect! I'm not sure I'll want to install a package for it since it's something I'd only use every so often, but would save me countless hours in the long run!